# How to solve this argparse freeze issue?

Tags: python, python-2.7, command-line, terminal, argparse

I would like to create a very simple terminal menu that uses files and directories so I tried the following:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    p = argparse.ArgumentParser(NAME)

    p.add_argument('-data:', '--input_data', default=sys.stdin)
    p.add_argument('-labels:', '--targets', default=sys.stdin)
    p.add_argument('-input_directory:', '--input', default=sys.stdin)
    p.add_argument('-output_data:', '--output', default=sys.stdout)
    opts = p.parse_args()

    if not any([opts.input, opts.output, opts.targets,opts.input_data]):
        p.print_usage()
        quit()
        print '\npress -h to see the help\n'

    elif any([opts.targets,opts.input_data]):
        print '\ncompleted action\n'

        p.print_usage()
        #Recibe (datos, etiquetas)
        perform_stuff(opts.input_data, opts.targets)
        quit()

#Here is the problem:

    elif any([opts.input, opts.output]):
        print '\ncompleted action\n'
        retrive(opts.input)
        write(opts.output)
```

Note that for simplicity I omited the `perform_stuff(path/in/file, path/out/file)`, `retrive(opts.input)` and `write(opts.output)` implementation. The problem is that the only command that works is:

```
    if not any([opts.input, opts.output, opts.targets,opts.input_data]):
        p.print_usage()
        quit()
        print '\npress -h to see the help\n'

    elif any([opts.targets,opts.input_data]):
        print '\ncompleted action\n'

        p.print_usage()
        #Recibe (datos, etiquetas)
        perform_stuff(opts.input_data, opts.targets)
        quit()
```

On the other hand, when I try to run:

```
#Here is the problem:

    elif any([opts.input, opts.output]):
        print '\ncompleted action\n'
        retrive(opts.input)
        write(opts.output)
```

My simple program just freeze. I am new with argparse, I guess that the problem is correlated with the proper use of if/else statements. Therefore, How should I create the menu of my simple program?

Comment: Well from an argparse perspective, it looks like everything is okay. You should try debugging where is your program stuck.

Comment: Is there any way to create a better flow between each command (i.e. if a function is called, do the work, then stop)? @ibizaman

Comment: It's a matter of taste, but that will already do what you want. I suspect though you do not need to call quit(), unless it's one of your function. Either way that program should not freeze. Can you post what you implemented in your functions, how you call it to make it freeze and the output you see when that happens?

Comment: Thanks for the help @ibizaman, I added the functions that are stucking the menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I've cleaned up and condensed your code, with a focus on getting the if/else tree working.

In the parser I rewrote the `short options` as single characters.  I also left the defaults as `None`.  That makes `if` tests easier.  (what should it do if `opts.input` is `stdin` and you test `if not opts.input:`?).

```
import argparse
def quit():
    import sys
    sys.exit(1)

def perform_stuff(*args):
    print 'stuff', args

def retrive(*args):
    print 'retrieve', args        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    # single letter `-d` string; use default None
    p.add_argument('-d', '--input_data')
    p.add_argument('-t', '--targets')
    p.add_argument('-i', '--input')
    p.add_argument('-o', '--output')
    opts = p.parse_args()
    print 'opts', opts

    if not any([opts.input, opts.output, opts.targets, opts.input_data]):
        p.print_usage()
        print 'press -h to see the help'
        quit()

    elif any([opts.targets,opts.input_data]):
        perform_stuff(opts.input_data, opts.targets)
        quit()

    elif any([opts.input, opts.output]):
        retrive(opts.input, opts.output)
    else:
        print 'else'
```

Sample runs:

```
1814:~/mypy$ python stack36877714.py
opts Namespace(input=None, input_data=None, output=None, targets=None)
usage: stack36877714.py [-h] [-d INPUT_DATA] [-t TARGETS] [-i INPUT]
                        [-o OUTPUT]
press -h to see the help
1815:~/mypy$ python stack36877714.py -d input_data
opts Namespace(input=None, input_data='input_data', output=None, targets=None)
stuff ('input_data', None)
1815:~/mypy$ python stack36877714.py -t targets
opts Namespace(input=None, input_data=None, output=None, targets='targets')
stuff (None, 'targets')
1815:~/mypy$ python stack36877714.py -i input
opts Namespace(input='input', input_data=None, output=None, targets=None)
retrieve ('input', None)
1816:~/mypy$ python stack36877714.py -o output
opts Namespace(input=None, input_data=None, output='output', targets=None)
retrieve (None, 'output')
```

Your functions could be written like:

```
def retrieve(in_arg, out_arg):
    if in_arg is None:
        data = sys.stdin.read()
        # cannot open/close stdin
    else:
        with open(in_arg,'r') as f:
            data = f.read()
    if out_arg is None:
        # write to sys.stdout
    else:
        # write to open(out_arg,'w')
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I added more details.